# Condense nested for loop to improve processing time with text analysis python

Tags: performance, python-2.7, nested-loops, feature-selection

I am working on an untrained classifier model. I am working in Python 2.7. I have a loop. It looks like this:

```
    features = [0 for i in xrange(len(dictionary))]
    for bgrm in new_scored:
        for i in xrange(len(dictionary)):
            if bgrm[0] == dictionary[i]:
                features[i] = int(bgrm[1])
                break
```

I have a "dictionary" of bigrams that I have collected from a data set containing customer reviews and I would like to construct feature arrays of each review corresponding to the dictionary I have created. It would contain the frequencies of the bigrams found within the review of the features in the dictionary (I hope that makes sense). new_scored is a list of tuples which contains the bigrams found within a particular review paired with their relative frequency of occurrence in that review. The final feature arrays will be the same length as the original dictionary with few non zero entries.

The above works fine but I am looking at a data set of 13000 reviews, for each review to loop through this code is going to take for eeever (if my computer doesnt run out of RAM first). I have been sitting with it for a while and cannot see how I can condense it.

I am very new to python so I was hoping a more experienced could help with condensing it or perhaps point me in the right direction towards a library that will contain the function I need.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider making `dictionary` an actual `dict` object (or some fancier subclass of `dict` if it better suits your needs), as opposed to an iterable (`list` or `tuple` seems like what it is now).  `dictionary` could map bigrams as keys to an integer identifier that would identify a feature position.

If you refactor `dictionary` that way, then the loop can be rewritten as:

```
features = [0 for key in dictionary]
for bgram in new_scored:
    try:
        features[dictionary[bgram[0]]] = int(bgrm[1])
    except KeyError:
        # do something if the bigram is not in the dictionary for some reason
```

This should convert what was an O(n) traversal through `dictionary` into a hash lookup.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. It definately set me on the right path. I ended up converting both the new_scored and dictionary lists into type dict and then did this:           features = dictionary.copy()
        for bgram in scored:
            features[(bgram[0])] = int(bgram[1])

Comment: @PelonomiMoiloa I'm glad if I was able to help.